# How to make MobileFirst preview in chrome MobileBrowserSimulator to open Android tablet as default device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, maximo-anywhere

When I preview any one of the MaximoAnywhere applications eg. Inspection app (Android version), by default the BrowserSimulator is opening Android Phone device view. Is there a way to open Android tablet device view by default ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available as part of the MBS tool.

What you can do instead is have it load the preview as usual the first time.
But after that first time, keep the browser window opened the way you set it up with the device skin that you prefer and from there on just build your changes, and then in the browser simply click on the refresh button. The end result would be what you're looking for - to preview with the tablet skin that is already opened infront of you.